# Lazy Images in TableLayout

Tags: android

I am using web service in my application and somewhere need to display images in a **TableLayout** along with some text. But the problem is that there are number of images. Thus, when I am populating my **TableLayout** a lot of time is consumed in filling the complete table.

**Question :**

I have seen examples to populate lazy images in **ListView**. But just cant figure out how to do the same in **TableLayout**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fx. you can use this loader from LazyList

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/ImageLoader.java

and then in activity

```
class Activity ... {
 ImageLoader loader = null;
 onCreate(...){
   ...
   loader = new ImageLoader(this);
   ImageView img = findImageView1();
   String imageUrl = "http://image1";
   img.setTag(imageUrl);
   loader.DisplayImage(imageUrl, this, img);

   img = findImageView2();
   imageUrl = "http://image2";
   img.setTag(imageUrl);
   loader.DisplayImage(imageUrl, this, img);
   ....
   img = findImageViewN();
   imageUrl = "http://imageN";
   img.setTag(imageUrl);
   loader.DisplayImage(imageUrl, this, img);
 }
}
```

Comment: But how to handle LazyAdapter?

Comment: why do you need LazyAdapter? all you need is ImageLoader class and use it like i did in my example

Answer (score -1):

this imageloader is not working like lazy

means when i scroll down than other iamges is load this load all the images and than run

it is possible SEE BELOW IMAGE for lazy loading with table layout 
imageview create runtime and than add but when is complete load than display upto only backscreen appear before complete loading how to do lazy loading with this type of layout

[image]